# How can I retrieve the command line arguments from a program shortcut in the dock?

Tags: macos, command-line, dock

My question is the exact opposite of [this earlier one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/17476/44558). I am working on an open source application, which is published under 2 forms, pre-compiled binaries and source code.

I installed the pre-compiled binaries and it works perfectly, with a nice little icon in the dock.

I compiled the source code successfully, but I get a runtime error when I launch it. After investigation I suspect this app needs command-line options to run correctly.

So my question is: if my assumptions are correct and the working version is actually defining command line arguments, **how can I retrieve the CL arguments from the packaged app**?

If it makes any difference, the app I'm talking about is [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/), and I'm running OS X Version 10.8.2

Comment: I assume you are from Windows - Dock icons n OSK are not shortcuts and don't have extra command line arguments, they just run as if you clickecd on the app in finder or ran using `open` from the command line

Comment: What runtime error do you get?

Comment: "[Launcher Error] No Runtime key in dictionary". If you look for this error in the code, you can clearly see that it comes from bad arguments given to the `main` function.

Comment: @mark: For what it's worth, I come from a Linux background, haven't touched Windows in ages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not the command line. From the code [here](http://svn.cyberduck.ch/tags/release-4-1-3/source/ch/cyberduck/ui/cocoa/utils.c)

```
// Get an instance of the non-localized keys.
CFDictionaryRef bundleInfoDict = CFBundleGetInfoDictionary(mainBundleRef);  
if(NULL == bundleInfoDict) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[Launcher Error] No info dictionary.\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

where mainBundleRef refers to the .app bundle.

The problem is that the Info.plist inside the app (/Applications/Cyberduck.app/Contents/Info.plist) does not have the normal keys in it. It has been corrupted in some way.The one in the code repository looks OK at a glance. For information about the structure I would look at the Apple development [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW1).

The easiest fix would be to redownload and install the application.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at the code, although that was not the intent of my question at all. The answer I was looking for was indeed to look in the `Info.plist` file. I found what I needed; it's irrelevant to the question asked, so I'll just [mark it here](http://trac.cyberduck.ch/ticket/6768) in case someone stumbles upon this page.